# Passing value from child component to parent component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm only starting to work with React and now trying to create "To Do List", now I need to pass value from input in child functional component to parent functional component, but don't know how to do that.

I need to pass 'value' from 'Form' component to 'App' component to add new value to values array, but components are in different files.

Parent component code:

```
const App = () => {

  const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
  'First To Do',
  'Second To Do',
  'Third To Do',
  ]);  

  return (

   <div className='app'>
    <Form />
    <ToDoList items={items} />
   </div>

  );

}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Child component code:

```
const Form = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  function handleValueChange(e) {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(value);
    alert('New To Do was added.');
    setValue('');
  }


  return (
    <div className={classes.addingForm}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input className={classes.myInput} type='text' value={value} onChange={handleValueChange}/>
            <input className={classes.mySubmit} type='submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>
    </div>
  )

};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define value and setValue in the App component and pass it as props to Form component

// App.js

```
const App = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = React.useState([
        "First To Do",
        "Second To Do",
        "Third To Do",
    ]);
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        // you can log the new value here if the form is submitted
        console.log(value);
    }, [value]);

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Form setValue={setValue} />
            <ToDoList items={items} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

// Child component code:

```
const Form = ({ setValue }) => {
    function handleValueChange(e) {
        setValue(e.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(value);
        alert("New To Do was added.");
        setValue("");
    }

    return (
        <div className={classes.addingForm}>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    className={classes.myInput}
                    type="text"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleValueChange}
                />
                <input
                    className={classes.mySubmit}
                    type="submit"
                    value="Submit"
                />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Form;
```